# "That was all we needed" - Is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, past-tense

> "Same motive. Same will. That was all we needed to work together."

I wanted this to be more of a casual sentence so I skipped adding 'the' before 'same.'

But I'm not sure if the second part, "That was all we needed," has to be written as "they were all we needed." I think it's ugly.

Comment: Regardless of its "true" correctness, it is a perfectly natural way to say the sentence in common speech. Are you writing a movie? a play? a book? a memoir? Is the character a Yale graduate? an English teacher? a deckhand? Are they speaking over dinner? at an awards ceremony? in a bar? These will all determine if the sentence is okay.

Comment: "Questions asking for someone to find and correct errors or improve the phrasing are considered requests for proofreading and are off-topic. Please edit your question to focus on something in particular that you are unsure about; if that's not possible, see websites for proofreading instead."

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this question will be closed because it will be viewed as a matter of taste and therefore of opinion.

I want to point out, however, that the two choices have slightly different meanings. “That” focuses on the identity of motive and will between two or more people; it is singular. “They” focuses on the dual nature of the mutual agreement. So choose whichever best suits your intended meaning.